# Formatting string to certain character limit in Python

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a code that outputs a whole bunch of numbers after doing some maths on them. At one point in the code they are rounded off with `numpy.rint`, and in certain cases (I believe when a 9 is rounded to a 10) I end up with a trailing zero that I do not want. I have some code that looks sort-of like this

```
ra3n = ra3/60 * 10
ra3n = np.rint(ra3n)
ra3n = ra3n.astype(str) ##there is a good reason that this needs to be a string
```

I need all of the resulting `ra3n` to be 5 characters long, but occasionally one pops out as 6 characters long. How would I format this properly? Keep in mind I'm a total python noob, so I might need it spelled out for me =)

EDIT:

Here's my output:

```
00244-2451
00244-2702
00278-0629
00286-1614
00295-1101
002910-0546
00303+0711
00305+2246
00348+2604
003410+0423
00355-0204
00359+1236
00360-0931
00386-1210
```

The instances where there are six digits instead of 5 in the first half of the string are the erroneous ones; those trailing zeroes should not be there.

Comment: `ra3n.astype('|S5')`?

Comment: Attempted this, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`ra3n = ra3n[:-1] if ra3n[-1] == '0' else ra3n`

There's probably a better solution, but I'm not sure I really understand your issue without seeing some output.

Comment: Edited with my output.

Answer (score 2):

You change the type of `ra3n`, which is poor programming practice. Try this.

```
ra3n = format(ra3/60.*10., '5f')[:5]
```

This gives exactly five characters. Note that if the string would usually be six characters long, this cuts off the last character, for good or for bad. Note also that I included decimal points in the 60 and 10 numbers: this guarantees that floating-point division will be used, rather than integer division if this is done in Python 2.

Comment: Okay, cool. I'm having a problem though: I use numpy.loadtxt to import my arrays, and I have to import as ``str`` because there are a bunch of different data types. So I then use ``ra3 = ra3.astype(float)`` just before the line you suggested, but it's giving me ``Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`` for the line you gave me.

Comment: @uhurulol: Oops, I had a typo: I wrote `r13` rather than `ra3`. Try it now. Or perhaps use `format(float(ra3)/60.*10., '5f')[:5]`.

Comment: I got that typo don't worry, but it's still not working ><

Comment: The second suggestion you made gives this error: ``TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
``

Comment: @uhurulol: I don't know numpy, so I am not sure what is happening, I can only guess. What exactly is the type of `ra3`?

Comment: It's imported as a string, but it's a float (38.12, 29.43, etc).